# Is it possible to change SparkContext.sparkUser() AFTER the SparkContext has been initialized?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I initialize a `SparkContext` to run multiple SparkSQL queries. Inside this `SparkContext`, I create a bunch of tables and every table has to have a different owner, however, Spark uses the `sparkUser` as the table owner.

So I was wondering if it is possible to change the `sparkUser` **after** the `SparkContext` has already been initialized?

Comment: no is also an answer

Comment: Why was this question downvoted again? It's a perfectly legitimate question. Just because it is not possible to do doesn't make it any less of a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, by simple deduction based on this https://forums.databricks.com/questions/21371/how-to-change-the-user-running-the-spark-job.html  question to Databricks in which they state you need to do that during cluster creation.